# Simple Application Configuration with Stripes

Tags: web, stripes

I'm using Stripes. I just want to add some parameters that will be used at the application start up for some configuration. What is the simplest (or best) way of doing this? Properties, web.xml or what? I searched the stripes book (also website) but couldn't find a clear answer.

I'd normally use an appConfig.properties file and a listener class like this:

```
public class ConfigLoader implements  javax.servlet.ServletContextListener {

public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.put(sce, sce);
    try {
        properties.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("appConfig.properties"));
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getResource("").getFile());

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new ExceptionAdapter(ex);
    }        
}

public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

The nice thing about Stripes is that beyond it's little world of binding and such, it doesn't have a large footprint. So you can do anything you want. If you're happy with your appConfig.properties, then by all means keep using that.